# Adding custom headers in ReportNG Report

Tags: testng, reportng

I am using ReportNg to generate reports for TestNg tests. I used the org.uncommons.reportng.title in my pom.xml to generate the report title . But along with title I want to add Environment details like URl, OS etc. How can do this in ReportNG.
I have been able to do this with a CustomizedReporter implementing IReporter but needs to do this with ReportNg. 
Can someone please let me know how to do this??

Answer (score 1):

ReportNG doesn't currently support any customisation like this.  You would have to make changes to ReportNG itself (subclass `HTMLReporter` and modify the Velocity templates) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think reportNG has more functionality that allows such customizations.
However, you can take the resulting report, and edit the HTML, add the logo of your company, add titles and basically whatever you like.

This, for example, adds an image to your HTML:

```
<h2>My Company Logo</h2>
<img border="0" src="/images/mylogo.jpg" alt="company logo" width="304" height="228">
```